# setting iptables rules to allow traffic of Ha-proxy

Tags: centos, haproxy, high-availability, centos7

Hey everyone I am new to Ha-Proxy and also with iptables rules, my case 
I have successfully setup 3 VirtualBox CentOS instance for practise  one designated as a LoadServer 
and the rest of the two are webclient. Network Settings of the webclient in virtualbox
set as Bridge, and install nginx, my web application, and allow port 80, port 443 and 
so on. However when I install Ha-Proxy and check the status of the 3 machines using 
http://LoadServer/stats it seem all of em are down. My question how do I allow the traffic 
back and forth from LoadServer to the two webclient? Your suggestion will be highly appreciated. 
thank you.

```
          LoadServer 192.168.0.125
          web1: 192.168.0.121
          web2: 192.168.0.122
```

haproxy.cfg

```
      backend LB 192.168.0.125:80
        mode http
        stats enable
        stats hide-version
        stats uri /stats
        stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
        stats auth haproxy:redhat       
        balance roundrobin          
        option httpchk
        option  httpclose
        option forwardfor
        cookie LB insert
        server web1-srv 192.168.0.121:80 cookie web1-srv check      # backend server.
        server web2-srv 192.168.0.122:80 cookie web2-srv check  # backend server.
```

Comment: Why do you believe iptables to be the problem? Have you inspected the iptables rules on these machines? Does disabling iptables (as a test) fix the problem?

Comment: Centos7 in Virtualbox by default block the web browser from accessing NGINX instance. You can curl or ping but not able to access it via port 80. I was able to do this by installing iptables and allow the traffic of web server the http Port 80 and https port 443.

Comment: Your IP addresses in the first list and in the `haproxy.cfg` file don't match but if you added the right ip/port rules to iptables then it should work. If it doesn't you should see if you can connect from one to the other manually and go from there.

Comment: The reason I believe it has something to do with iptables rules because HAProxy works has a reverse-proxy. Which means it maintains 2 connections when allowing a client to cross it. And iptables allow only specific port or rules to access.

Comment: I already updated it thats the original ip.

Comment: I have no problem connecting from the 3. ssh, ftp, http or vsftp

Comment: If you can connect from each host to each other host on the ports you believe haproxy is using why do you believe iptables is the problem? Does the haproxy log say anything about this issue? Can you see the haproxy connections on the servers? (In the output from `ss`?)

Comment: i dont know what port the haproxy is using.